# Laravel 5.2 route regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the following route to capture urls like www.example.com/@username but it gives me a 404 error.

```
Route::get('{user}', 'UserController@showProfile')->where('user', '(?<=\s|^)@([\w@]+)');
```

The regex works just fine, because if i'm using the following route it outputs the correct result.

```
Route::get('{user}', 'UserController@showProfile')
```

and

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function showProfile($user)
    {
        $out = array();
        $re = "/(?<=\\s|^)@([\\w@]+)/";

        preg_match_all($re, $user, $out);

        dd($out);
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your lookbehind and the capture group from your route regex. Try to use the most simple solution possible, like this `^@[\w]+$`. And since your route will always start with **@** instead of capturing the username you can do `$user = substr($user, 1);`.

Also I would recommend to use route model binding, so you can have an instance of an existing user directly in your controller. In your **RouteServiceProvider@boot** add this:

```
    $router->bind( 'user', function ( $username ) {
        return User::whereUsername( substr($username, 1) )->firstOrFail();
    });
```

And then inside your controller your method will look like this:

`public function showProfile( User $user ){ ...`